# Git слияние веток

Tags: git

**Имеется задание:**
ветка master в которой есть файл test3.py с кодом print("Hello, World!"), необходимо создать еще две ветки comment и rating, и в каждой ветке в этом же файле изменить код print("Comment was added") и print("My new rating") соответственно.
После этого все ветки нужно слить в одну, разрешив конфликт, чтобы в файле осталось три строчки с кодом

```
print("Hello, World!")
print("Comment was added")
print("My new rating")
```

Пытаюсь сделать так:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "hello world"
$ git branch rating_branch
$ git checkout rating_branch     
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "rating"
$ git checkout master
$ git branch comment_branch
$ git checkout comment_branch   
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "comment"
$ git checkout master
$ git merge rating_branch comment_branch
```

Итог всего этого получается файл с двумя строками кода

```
print("Comment was added")
print("My new rating")
```

а `print("Hello, World!")` затирается, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Добавьте содержимое файла из промежуточных веток.

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, при слиянии нескольких веток сразу стоит проверять результат перед коммитом. Для этого есть параметр `--no-commit` - выполняет слияние и ждет подтверждения командой `commit`. Можно вручную поправить результат слияния как угодно.

Во-вторых, так как ветка rating_branch начинается от master, вполне возможно, что сначала был сделан fast-forward до нее, где строки print("Hello, World!") уже нет. Чтобы предотвратить fast-forward есть параметр `--no-ff`.

Я рекомендую всегда использовать эти два параметра при слиянии нескольких веток

```
git merge --no-ff --no-commit rating_branch comment_branch
git commit
```

Comment: Выучите стратегию *octopus*.